# Node js return before for loop execute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node js, in my project one of the function not wait till for loop execute

```
let prepareExecution = (type) => {
 let files = [];
 let filestodelete = [];
 let data = {};
 data.files = files;
 data.filestodelete = filestodelete;
 let list = ['vpl_run.sh','vpl_debug.sh', 'vpl_evaluate.sh', 'vpl_evaluate.cases'];
 for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
  let fileName = list[i];
  let testCase = "Case1";
  let test = {};
  test[fileName] = testCase;
  console.log(test)
  data.files.push(test);
 }
 let test = {};
 test.fileName = 1;
 data.filestodelete.push(test);
 return data;
}
```

What I got is

```
{
  "files": {},
  "filestodelete": {
    "fileName": 1
  }
}
```

Output I need is

```
{
 "files": { 'vpl_run.sh': 'Case1'},
 "filestodelete": {
   "fileName": 1
  }
}
```

Can you please any one guide me for the above issue

Comment: What's the `type` argument for? That does nothing in your code

Comment: You have so many redundant variables in your code

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The code you posted does return `{"files":[{"vpl_run.sh":"Case1"},{"vpl_debug.sh":"Case1"},{"vpl_evaluate.sh":"Case1"},{"vpl_evaluate.cases":"Case1"}],"filestodelete":[{"fileName":1}]}`

Comment: Do you really write code with ONE space of indentation?

Comment: Your code does not generate either what you said it did or what you want. `.push()` is a method on an array and you don't show any arrays in either output.  This whole question is messed up right now.  You can't start with an array and use `.push()` on it and end up with a plain object like you show in both set of your output.

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote your code slightly because all the redundant variables annoyed me a bit,

```
let prepareExecution = (type) => {
 let data = {};
 data.files = [];
 data.filestodelete = [];
 let list = ['vpl_run.sh','vpl_debug.sh', 'vpl_evaluate.sh', 'vpl_evaluate.cases'];
 for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
  let fileName = list[i];
  let test = {};
  test[fileName] = "Case1";
  console.log(test);
  data.files.push(test);
 }
 let test = {};
 test.fileName = 1;
 data.filestodelete.push(test);
 return data;
}
```

But both the function in your question and this function here return

```
{ files:
   [ { 'vpl_run.sh': 'Case1' },
     { 'vpl_debug.sh': 'Case1' },
     { 'vpl_evaluate.sh': 'Case1' },
     { 'vpl_evaluate.cases': 'Case1' } ],
  filestodelete: [ { fileName: 1 } ] }
```

when I run them in node v7.4.0

Comment: What did you fix?  What was the problem in the OP's code?